# Is there a windowMaxWidthMajor and windowMaxWidthMinor for Android dialogs?

Tags: android, android-layout, dialog, modal-dialog

For custom Android dialog boxes:

The attribute `android:windowMinWidthMajor` defines the minimum size for a dialog's width when it is along the major axis (that is the screen is landscape).

The attribute `android:windowMaxWidthMinor` defines the minimum size for a dialog's width when it is along the minor axis (that is the screen is portrait).

**Can we also define maximum sizes for a dialog's width?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would wrap your dialog in a LinearLayout and set the max width on it.

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:maxWidth="350dp" >

    <Rest of the XML for your dialog layout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is an example of how to line up a view using percentages for the min (10%) and max (90%).  It will set the left edge of the TextView or your dialog code to 10% of the screen width and the right edge at 90% of the screen width.  It usages a ConstraintLayout with Guidelines.  The TextView can be replaced with your dialog code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.10" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.90" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But my original intention was to set a minimum/maximum width between two percentages (e.g. `75% - 90%`). This solution does not solve this.

Comment: In that case, I would recommend that you use a ConstraintLayout and add two guides that can use percentages. I have updated my answer with an example.

Comment: Huh. I never thought about doing that before. Thanks!